# Proving integral inequality hold amongst $L^p$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a measurable set, $1\leq p<\infty$, $q$ the conjugate of $p$, and $g$ belong to
$L^q(E)$.

I am trying to show the following (as part of a proposition from Royden):

---

For every $\epsilon>0$, show there is a function $f\in L^1(E)$ such that,

$$\int f\cdot g > \left(||g||_{\infty}-\epsilon\right)||f||_{1}\,.\tag{1}$$

Written slightly different,

$$\int f\cdot g > \left(||g||_{\infty}-\epsilon\right)\int|f|\,.\tag{1}$$

---

In other words, can anyone tell me what $f\in L^1(E)$ satisfies $(1)$?

*Note: the conjugate function of $g$, $g^*$, is invalid as $q=\infty$.*

Comment: $f =sgn(g)\chi_{\{x: |g(x)| \geq \|g\|_{\infty}-\epsilon\}}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is it obvious this is in $L^1$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I think I see how this function works, but could you write a post working this out?

Comment: @ClementC. Good point. But multplying my $f$ with charatcteristic function of any set of finite measure works.  On second thoughts $f=0$ is good enough!.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: True, I just realized it should be $>$, not $\geq$...Fixed!

Comment: @D.Math Can you be a little more specific about where that question comes from?

Comment: @ClementC. Sure. Define $T(f)$ by $$T(f):=\int f\cdot g\text{ for all } f\in L^p(E).$$ Then, by proving this problem you show, for the $p=1$ & $q=\infty$ case, is that $T$ is that $T(f) \geq ||g||_{\infty}\cdot||f||_{1}$, further $|T(f)| \geq ||g||_{\infty}\cdot||f||_{1}$. So, by definition of the norm on $T$, i.e. $||T||:=\sup\{|T(f)|/||f||_{1}\}$, we have that $||g||_{\infty}\leq ||T||.$ From Holder's Inequality, you can show that $||T||\leq ||g||_{\infty}$. Therefore, combining both inequalities we have that $||T|| = ||g||_{\infty}$, for fixed $g\in L^{\infty}$ and every $f\in L^1$.

Comment: @ClementC. To add: For $1<p<\infty$, you can use the conjugate function of $g$, $g^*$, to prove $||T|| = ||g||_{q}$ holds for fixed $g\in L^{\infty}$ and every $f\in L^1$.

Comment: Some assumption like sigma finiteness of the measure is necessary. There exist measure spaces in which the only integrable function is the zero function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you explain why multiplying $f$ with characteristic function of any set of finite measure works? This is all done with respect to the Lebesgue Measure and Integral. So, in order for your $f$ to work it must be that the set $\{x:|g|>||g||_{\infty}-\epsilon\}$ is measurable.